# Arabic Language works in Window 7 but in Windows XP reversed again- WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, internationalization, right-to-left

I have an application in c# that is multi lingual.

Now the second language is arabic.

Problem:

In resource file i added the string as say:

Hello.

It is displayed as Hello in XP
While              olleH in windows 7

Any help is appreciated

EDIT:

We reverse the string i.e. Hello to oellH as while copying the arabic string they are reveresed

Comment: Are XP and win 7 region and language settings same? Especially settings for non-unicode languages?

Comment: @VladL I am not sure. Can you please tell what need to be change

Comment: look into windows control panel / regional and language settings and compare them

Comment: @VladL Yes they are same. DO i need to install some language pack first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with XP and not windows 7.

For XP i need to go to **Region and Settings** in control panel.

Click second tab "Languages"

Click Thai.. Support checkbox

And click ok

It will ask for XP cd

and that's it.....